# Finding the index of a substring within a CSV file

Tags: python

I have written some code that creates a function for count how many times a substring appears within a string, the second part of this function is supposed to return, is the index of each of those substring's.

The string is stored in a .csv file and where I run into problems is when I try to return the index of the substring's.

## 1. Import the text.csv file

```
import csv
data = open('text.csv', 'r')
read_data = csv.reader(data)
```

## 2. Complete function counter. The function should return the number of times the substring appears & their index

```
def counter(substring):
  ss_counter = 0
  for substring in read_data:
    ss_counter = ss_counter + 1
    print('Counter = ', ss_counter)
    print('Index = ', substring.index)
```

## 3. Do not edit the code below

```
counter("TCA")
```

The error I get from the .index is

built-in method index of list object at 0x7f4519700208

Comment: The error is indicating the `index` is a method. Try `print('Index = ', substring.index())`

Comment: Also another error in your `for substring in read_data:`. You are overwriting your `substring` parameter with another variable with the same name, therefore now you are iterating character by character through read_data.

Comment: You question is unclear. What do you mean by "index"? Also a CSV file is composed of rows of data which may have multiple fields in row, so you need to specify what string you're search for substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you fix when I mention in my comment, it won't work like you expect.

The `read_data` variable is an object that will iterate over the lines of the file (see the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#)). So inside the function, when you do `for substring in read_data`, the substring variable (which you override the parameter), contains an individual line, where each element is the comma separated value.

Check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) for the `list` method `index`. You have to pass into the `index()` function the substring you're looking for INSIDE the list. But because you overrode the substring you were looking for, that's impossible now.

As a side note, it's possible that the substring could occur two or more times, and your current code doesn't take that into account.

So one solution could be:

```
def counter(substring):
    ss_counter = 0
    for row in read_data:
        ss_counter = ss_counter + 1
        print('Counter = ', ss_counter)
        print('Index = ', row.index(substring))
```

I'll let you figure out how to take into account multiple occurrences in a given row.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is overwriting `substring` as a variable, so within the for loop, substring is actually referring to a row in the csv file, not the original substring you were hoping to search for. You want to iterate through your read_data for every row, and then iterate through every row looking for a match for every possible starting point in that row, starting at index=0. I also suggest you pass the `read_data` as a second parameter instead of using the global variable. Note, this function will count overlapping substring as two separate substrings (i.e. if `substring = 'aa'` and `read_data = ['aaaa']`, this will say there are three occurrences of substring in the first row).

```
def counter(substring, readData):
    ss_counter = 0
    # Iterate through the read_data string from index 0 to the nth to the last index, with n = length of the substring
    for row in read_data:      
        for i in range(0, len(row) - len(substring) + 1):
            if row[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
                ss_counter += 1
                print('Counter = ', ss_counter)
                print('Index = ', i)

counter(substring, read_data)
```

Edit: Changed read_data to be a list of rows (list of strings).

Comment: This was very helpful, I'll have to look for your for loop and practice more as that is more complex than what I have been using previously.

Note that I am not allowed to edit the last line of code, which means my function is only allowed to take 1 argument.

I'll keep at it tho, thanks for the help.